# Angular 6 Material Stepper mat-step nested reactive forms

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-reactive-forms, angular-material-stepper

Hello I have issue with dynamic stepper where I try to generate steps with form for each step. Forms comes from nested FormGroup object. 
Scenario goes along:

Form:

```
this.formGroupNested = _formBuilder.group({
      formGroup1: _formBuilder.group({
        name: new FormControl(),
        displayName: new FormControl(),
        email: new FormControl(),
        adult: new FormControl(),
        selectField: new FormControl()
      }),
      formGroup2: _formBuilder.group({
        firstName: new FormControl(),
        lastName: new FormControl()
      })
    });
```

stepper.html

```
  <mat-horizontal-stepper [linear]="isLinear" #stepperDelivery>
    <mat-step *ngFor="let step of steps" [stepControl]="step">
        <ng-template matStepLabel>Fill out your name</ng-template>
        <!-- <form [formGroup]="step">

        </form> -->
    </mat-step>
  </mat-horizontal-stepper>
```

I have worked form html, but structure doesnt fit to stepper. Here is working example, in [...] are controls

```
<form
  *ngIf="messages; else loading"  
  [formGroup]="formGroupNested"
  [connectForm]="forms">
    <div
      formGroupName="formGroup1">
      <h1>{{ messages.authentication.form.steps.one.title }}</h1>
      <uland-text-field
      [formGroup]="formGroupNested.controls.formGroup1"
      [controlName]="'name'"
      [id]="'name'"
      [label]="messages.authentication.name.label"
      [placeholder]="messages.authentication.name.placeholder"
      [isReadOnly]="false"
      ></uland-text-field>
      [...]
    </div>
    <div 
      formGroupName="formGroup2">
      <h1>{{ messages.authentication.form.steps.two.title }}</h1>
      [...]
    </div>
</form>
```

Do you have any ideas how to accomplish this goal? I thought about `ng-template` with template alias for generate steps.
Regards!

EDIT: Without nested forms, my stepper looks like this, and I guess its more easy to maintenance:

```
  <mat-horizontal-stepper [linear]="isLinear" #stepperDelivery>
    <mat-step [stepControl]="formGroup">
        <ng-template matStepLabel>Fill out your name</ng-template>
        <cms-development-form
        [messages]="messages"
        [formGroup]="formGroupSingle">
        </cms-development-form>
    </mat-step>
  </mat-horizontal-stepper>
```

Comment: is your problem about displaying the right formGroup in each step?

Comment: Just wondering should I use simple reactive forms for each step, or can I use complete nested reactive form. With big nested forms there is problem with html, because there is only one <form> tag and it's not fit to stepper structure, which predicting new form for each step.

Answer (score 1):

Use FormArray to create Dynamic Forms.Also Please find implemented example in given GitHub example: [You can use the reference to create your dynamic components](https://github.com/shashankgpt/csnoop/tree/master/src/app/blog/register-blog)

```
TS:
  form: FormArray;

ngOnInit() {
    this.formGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
      form : this.formBuilder.array([this.init2()])
    });
  }
  addItem() {
    this.form = this.formGroup.get('form') as FormArray;
    this.form.push(this.init2());
  }
  init2() {
    return this.formBuilder.group({
      blogHeading: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
        });
  }
HTML:
   <form [formGroup]="formGroup">
      <mat-horizontal-stepper  formArrayName="form">
      <mat-step [formGroupName]="i" *ngFor="let customerGroup of formGroup.controls.form.controls; let i = index">
        <ng-template matStepLabel>Step {{i + 1}}</ng-template>
        <mat-form-field>
            <input matInput placeholder="blogHeading" formControlName="blogHeading" required>
            <mat-error *ngIf="!(f2.blogHeading.valid && f2.blogHeading.touched)">
              Username is Required
            </mat-error>
          </mat-form-field>
                <div>
          <button mat-button  (click)="addItem()">New Page</button>
      </div>
      </mat-step>
    </mat-horizontal-stepper>
  </form>
```